# Different hover behavior inside a a-tag. Issue in IE 8+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, text-decorations

I have the following problem with the Internet Explorer 8+. It works in all other Browsers.

I dont want a underline hover effect on the i-tag inside the a-tag. The IE 8+ Ignores the hover pseudoclass on the i-tag. 
Here ist the HTML-Code:

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-print"></i>Print</a>
```

This is the associated CSS-Code:

```
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
a i:hover {text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: So you are wanting the text to be underlined but the icon not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap "print" in a `span`

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-print"></i><span>Print</span></a>
```

and in css

```
a {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover > span { text-decoration:underline;}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreiTerecoasa/SMbUp/)

Comment: I was afraid that this is the only solution :(

Answer (score 0):

This will never works dude because the a-tag contain the i-tag and in your CSS code you say

`a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}`

everything inside the a-tag will be underlined ... so the only solution is to **separate the i-tag** from a-tag